# Out of order mempool TX

Tags: mempool

I notice that mempool messages result in multiple tx messages, usually completely out of order.

What I generally do is re-queue the message until the parent is processed, however that doesn't seem to be the right approach. If the parent can't be verified, shouldn't it be discarded immediately?

In a hostile scenario I could receive an unsolicited tx that relies on an unseen parent. What are the best practices here? Just wait up until N seconds and then discard?

Comment: If you are attempting to replicate Bitcoin Core behavior, look into how the orphan pool operates.

Comment: This thread seems to illuminate the issue, https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/3566  It still seems odd that a high percentage of transactions on a mempool sync would go into the orphan map first instead of being ordered by the relaying node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the parent can't be verified, shouldn't it be discarded immediately?

Then you risk needing to redownload that transaction.

> What are the best practices here? Just wait up until N seconds and then discard?

I think what bitcoin does, adding it to a size-limited cache, works well in practice. You just have to make sure that when you receive the parent you broadcast `inv`s for both the parent and the child (assuming the child is still in the size-limited cache).